# How does one add padding to Bootstrap 3's container without screwing up the grid?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background, twitter-bootstrap-3, padding

Many site designs call for a dark background with a lighter foreground page that contains the site's content. When using Bootstrap, it seems logical that one would merely apply the light color to the .container div and be done with it. However, Bootstrap's container does not provide any padding between its edges and the columns within, so this solution provides a light background but with the column content flush with the edges - not a good look.

This is a common problem and there are several solutions on stackoverflow and elsewhere for Bootstrap 2, but I couldn't find anything useful for Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 4):

One of the Bootstrap 2 solutions involved using .container-fluid which switches the internal grid from pixel to percentage based. Then one may apply padding to a a background div within .container-fluid and the internal columns will seamlessly adjust to fit. This seemed like a good approach, but the specific CSS used to tweak some of the other styles didn't work with Bootstrap 3.

After digging through the Bootstrap source, I noticed that the only difference between the .container and .container-fluid rules, in grid.less are three media queries. I wrapped my page's content in .container-fluid then overrode its definition with one that included the media queries so that the page content would respond the same as the header and footer, which use the standard .container.

Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 3 Container Padding Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="page-container">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="page-bg">
         <!-- PAGE CONTENT -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And then the .less:

```
.page-container > .container-fluid:first-child {
  .container-fixed();

  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    width: @container-sm;
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    width: @container-md;
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    width: @container-lg;
  }
}
```

Then added padding to the .page-container div:

```
.page-container {
  .page-bg {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
  }
}

body {
  background-color: #333
}
```

This seems to work. I haven't completed the styling for the interfaces that will reside within this container yet so there could be issues down the road but everything seems to render fine so far.

[Here is a working example of this solution on codepen.io.](http://codepen.io/jmcmichael/full/445009b05aff90ab7461c8c87efbec4c/)

Note that the solution above uses less.css after including Bootstrap's variables and mixins .less files. Here's the compiled CSS:

```
.page-container > .container-fluid:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .page-container > .container-fluid:first-child {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .page-container > .container-fluid:first-child {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .page-container > .container-fluid:first-child {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
.page-container .page-bg {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
body {
  background-color: #333333;
}
```

Comment: For clarity, what is the purpose of the .page-container div? Thanks!

Comment: I used .page-container as a layout container near the root of the main page template of the app. It's so that if I want to have a page that has multiple horizontal layout types, I can mix in page-container divs with maybe something like banner-container divs that extend the full width of the page instead of limiting width to the media query breakpoints. It's not necessary to include for this technique to work properly.